Postgresql shows strange performance difference with similar queries
I have two postgres tables defined by this schema:
create table tableA (id int not null primary key);
create table tableB (id int not null primary key, tableA_id int null, 
foreign key(tableA_id) references tableA(id));

I also have an index on tableB.tableA_id.
Each table has about 50 millions of rows.
I have to take all rows from tableA which are not in tableB. I wrote this query (NB the real query includes more columns and joins, but i semplified it to be more clear)
select a.* from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id = b.tableA_id where b.id is null

This query was correct tooks 11 hours to finished. After many tries, i changed the query in this way:
select a.* from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id = b.tableA_id where b.tableA_id is null

I changed only the where condition, istead of b.id is null I wrote b.tableA_id is null. This query tooks only 15 minutes to run.
Why am i getting this difference? What is the real difference between theese queries?

b.id is null and b.tableA_id is null are not the same condition in the where clause. So what is the difference between these queries - that is the difference. They are different queries.

the join is the same, the where condition is "different". But it is not really different, because b.id is null if and only if b.tableA_id is null if and only if the row is not in tableB

No, they are different. One queries checks if b.id is null. The other checks if b.TableA_id is null. Your question is what's the difference and this is the answer. It is entirely possible that the first query is fast and the second is slow. There is nothing else to say. I assume you want to improve the performance of the second query - is that so? However, if as you say the RESULT of the two queries is the same, then use the first as it is faster - that would be the faster way to write this query (presumably because it creates a better execution plan).

Please add EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output to the question.

It's somewhat reproducible based on the details you gave.
The first one likely results in a plain old left join and then has to filter that to discard the rows with b.id is null. You're referencing two different columns of the right table, joining on one and filtering on another - unless the index includes it as inert payload or you indexed both of those, you won't get a quick index-only scan because one of the columns isn't available in it, so the db has to jump from the index to the heap (table) to fetch is separately.
 Gather  (cost=8984.12..20659.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=695.053..1301.412 rows=224552 loops=1)
   ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=7984.12..19659.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=627.898..932.214 rows=112276 loops=2)
         Output: a.id
         Hash Cond: (a.id = b.tablea_id)
         Filter: (b.id IS NULL)
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.tablea a  (cost=0.00..5532.50 rows=331950 width=4) (actual time=0.008..90.720 rows=250000 loops=2)
               Output: a.id
         ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=4122.94..4122.94 rows=235294 width=8) (actual time=252.246..252.246 rows=200000 loops=2)
               Output: b.tablea_id, b.id
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.tableb b  (cost=0.00..4122.94 rows=235294 width=8) (actual time=0.015..95.427 rows=200000 loops=2)
                     Output: b.tablea_id, b.id
 Execution Time: 1321.167 ms

The second one results in an anti-join which only has to do half the job. You're also referencing just a single column in the right table, and it's the one you've indexed, which likely gets you an upgrade from a sequential scan to the index-only.
 Merge Anti Join  (cost=1.59..28842.63 rows=273998 width=4) (actual time=0.099..413.614 rows=224552 loops=1)
   Output: a.id 
   Merge Cond: (a.id = b.tablea_id) 
   ->  Index Only Scan using tablea_pkey on public.tablea a  (cost=0.42..12996.42 rows=500000 width=4) (actual time=0.082..118.190 rows=500000 loops=1) 
         Output: a.id 
         Heap Fetches: 0 
   ->  Index Only Scan using tableb_tablea_id_idx on public.tableb b  (cost=0.42..9596.42 rows=400000 width=4) (actual time=0.014..124.488 rows=400000 loops=1) 
         Output: b.tablea_id 
         Heap Fetches: 0 
 Execution Time: 441.053 ms |

Ideally, PostgreSQL should notice that b.id isn't a nullable column so the only case when it holds a null is when it's a mismatch row in a left join, meaning that you're effectively requesting the same anti-join. Unfortunately, as of version 16, the planner doesn't go that far in reading into your statements.
